# Animate ui ul to left and right - not circular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

Want to display 3 items from ul at a time. And when user clicks to the next arrow each element is traversed and when control reaches to last item i.e 3rd item , next three items should be shown in place of first three items.

The list should not be circular, means after last item in the list there must not be first item.

Have created fiddle but it traversing in circular fashion. 
I am traversing list using this,

```
$("#rightArrow").click(function (e) {
    var curr = $("#itemsListBox ul li:last");
    curr.parent().prepend(curr);
});
$("#leftArrow").click(function (e) {
    var curr = $("#itemsListBox ul li:first");
    curr.parent().append(curr);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N6XrL/

Comment: Just animate the margin left of the UL and reset it back to 0/disable the right button when the end of the slideshow is reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply hide and show the appropriate element instead of appending/prepending:

http://jsfiddle.net/N6XrL/2/

```
var $elements = $("#itemsListBox ul li");
var count = $elements.length;
var showNum = 3;
var counter = 0;

$("#rightArrow").click(function (e) {
    if (counter + showNum < count) {
        counter++;
    }
    display();
});

$("#leftArrow").click(function (e) {
    if (counter > 0) {
        counter--;
    }
    display();
});

function display() {
    $elements.hide();    
    $elements.slice(counter, counter + showNum).show();
}

display();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should keep track of you current picture. like in following code.

```
var items_count = $("#itemsListBox ul li").length, current_item_counter=0;

$("#rightArrow").click(function(e) {
    if(current_item_counter<items_count)
    {
        var curr =  $("#itemsListBox ul li:last");
        curr.parent().prepend(curr);
        current_item_counter++;
    }
});
$("#leftArrow").click(function(e) {
    if(current_item_counter> 0)
    {
        var curr =  $("#itemsListBox ul li:first");
        curr.parent().append(curr);
        current_item_counter--;
    }
});
```

here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N6XrL/3/).